# gmap3 / jquery where does fusion table layer fit in?

Tags: jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-fusion-tables, jquery-gmap3

below is a gmap3 jquery plug in for a google maps code. I am struggling to get a google fusion layer added into the code  without breaking anything else. how does the example on adding a fusion table layer fit into my code below? Thanks

```
<div id="gMap"></div>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
jQuery.noConflict(); jQuery(document).ready(function(){  
    //MAP ZOOM (0 to 20)
    var zoomLevel = 14,
    gMap = jQuery("#gMap"),
    //iPad,iPhone,iPod...
    deviceAgent = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase(),
    iPadiPhone = deviceAgent.match(/(iphone|ipod|ipad)/);

//iPad Stuff
if (iPadiPhone) {
    //ADD MAP CONTROLS AND POST ARROWS
    jQuery("#footer").prepend('<div class="markerNav" title="Prev" id="prevMarker">&lsaquo;</div><div id="markers"></div><div class="markerNav" title="Next" id="nextMarker">&rsaquo;</div><div id="mapTypeContainer"><div id="mapStyleContainer"><div id="mapStyle" class="satellite"></div></div><div id="mapType" title="Map Type" class="satellite"></div></div>');
} else {//IF NOT iPad
    jQuery('#zoomIn').live('click',function(){
        zoomLevel += 1;
        gMap.gmap3({action: 'setOptions', args:[{zoom:zoomLevel}]});
    });
    jQuery('#zoomOut').live('click',function(){
        zoomLevel -= 1;
        gMap.gmap3({action: 'setOptions', args:[{zoom:zoomLevel}]});
    });
    //ADD MAP CONTROLS AND POST ARROWS
    jQuery("#footer").prepend('<div class="markerNav" title="Prev" id="prevMarker">&lsaquo;</div><div id="markers"></div><div class="markerNav" title="Next" id="nextMarker">&rsaquo;</div><div id="mapTypeContainer"><div id="mapStyleContainer"><div id="mapStyle" class="satellite"></div></div><div id="mapType" title="Map Type" class="satellite"></div></div><div class="zoomControl" title="Zoom Out" id="zoomOut"><img src="images/zoomOut.png" alt="-" /></div><div class="zoomControl" title="Zoom In" id="zoomIn"><img src="images/zoomIn.png" alt="+" /></div>');
}    
    jQuery('body').prepend("<div id='target'></div>");
```

then it continues my making markers and loading them with a pan through functionality

```
gMap.gmap3({ 
        action: 'init',
        onces: {
          bounds_changed: function(){
            var number = 0;
            jQuery(this).gmap3({
              action:'getBounds', 
              callback: function (){

                add(jQuery(this), number += 1, "marker1", "map_post.html", "Steve", "40.48805717","-80.24950375", '<img width="95" height="95"  alt="" />');
                add(jQuery(this), number += 1, "marker2", "map_post.html","Steve","40.48973507","-80.19283214", '<img width="95" height="95" src="" alt="" />');
              }
            });
          }
        }
      },{ 
        action: 'setOptions', args:[{
            zoom:zoomLevel,
            scrollwheel:true,
            disableDefaultUI:true,
            disableDoubleClickZoom:false,
            draggable:true,
            mapTypeControl:false,
            panControl:false,
            scaleControl:false,
            streetViewControl:false,
            zoomControl:false,
            //MAP TYPE: 'roadmap', 'satellite', 'hybrid'
            mapTypeId:'roadmap'
        }]
    });

    function add(jQuerythis, i, title, link, excerpt, lati, longi, img){
      jQuerythis.gmap3({
        action : 'addMarker',
        lat:lati,
        lng:longi,
        //PIN MARKER IMAGE
        options: {icon: new google.maps.MarkerImage('images/pin.png')},
        events:{
            mouseover: function(marker){
                jQuerythis.css({cursor:'pointer'});
                jQuery('#markerTitle'+i+'').fadeIn({ duration: 200, queue: false }).animate({bottom:"32px"},{duration:200,queue:false});
                jQuery('.markerInfo').removeClass('activeInfo').hide();
                jQuery('#markerInfo'+i+'').addClass('activeInfo').show();
                jQuery('.marker').removeClass('activeMarker');
                jQuery('#marker'+i+'').addClass('activeMarker');
            },
            mouseout: function(){
                jQuerythis.css({cursor:'default'});
                jQuery('#markerTitle'+i+'').stop(true,true).fadeOut(200,function(){jQuery(this).css({bottom:"0"})});
            },
            click: function(marker){window.location = link}
        },
        callback: function(marker){
          var jQuerybutton = jQuery('<div id="marker'+i+'" class="marker"><div id="markerInfo'+i+'" class="markerInfo"><h2>'+title+'</a></h2><p>'+excerpt+'</p><div class="markerTotal">'+i+' / <span></span></div></div></div>');
          jQuerybutton.mouseover(function(){
              jQuerythis.gmap3({
                action:'panTo', 
                args:[marker.position]
              });
              jQuery("#target").stop(true,true).fadeIn(1200).delay(500).fadeOut(1200);
           });
          jQuery('#markers').append(jQuerybutton);
          var numbers = jQuery(".markerInfo").length;
          jQuery(".markerTotal span").html(numbers);
          if(i == 1){
            jQuery('.marker:first-child').addClass('activeMarker').mouseover();
          }
          jQuerythis.gmap3({
            action:'addOverlay',
            content: '<div id="markerTitle'+i+'" class="markerTitle">'+title+'</div>',
            latLng: marker.getPosition()
           });
        }           
      });
    }
```

with all this code I am lost on where to add the piece to overlay my fusion table and keep the markers.

this is the example of adding a fusion table to a new map. not an existing one:

```
function initialize() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.4, -122.1),
      zoom: 5,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    // Initialize the first layer
    var firstLayer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
      query: {
        select: 'geometry',
        from: '196LqydLhOq1Wl9612hNhcGoh4vUmRjTaiFvDhA'
      },
      map: map,
      suppressInfoWindows: true
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(firstLayer, 'click', function(e) {
      windowControl(e, infoWindow, map);
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it was the wrong version of gmap3. I was trying to put newer version code into older version. So I just looked up the code for the correct version. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

It should work simply by tacking the regular Google Fusion tables loading code on the end.

However, I'm wondering why you want to use Fusion tables. I explored it recently and ended up using KML instead because it's much more flexible. Just a suggestion.

Good luck :)

Comment: How would you get a reference to the map(needed for the layer)? Can you additionally explain where you see a flexibility of a  KMLLayer.

Comment: Hi there, you should be able to export from the Fusion tables to a KML layer. KML is a XML-based (basically HTML-style `<tag></tag>` based) language. This makes it super easy to read and it has a lot of useful functionality: https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference and https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlelementsinmaps
(KML is also supported by the script)

Comment: Actually, if you still want fusion tables I just found you a good example of how to do that with the API from their examples on Github:
https://github.com/jbdemonte/gmap3/blob/master/demo/Fusion%20Tables.html

Comment: yes what I am struggling with now is what Dr Molle mentioned. I cant seem to get the reference back to the map for the sample code to work.

Comment: Take a look at the example provided by the gmap3 guys that I linked. They have a callback with their API where you can make the map reference whatever you like (they chose just plain old 'map') and then you can use regular Google Maps API code. Try it out, if you still need a hand, I'd be happy to help :)